# Python Web scraping not capturing body

Tags: python, web-scraping, document-body

I'm trying to scrap a website 'http://www.healthmap.org/en/' but the info in the body is showing to have no elements.

Heres my code

```
*from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
import html5lib

webUrl = 'http://www.healthmap.org/en/'
baseUrl = webUrl
req = urllib2.build_opener()
req.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome/20.0')]
webpage = req.open(baseUrl)

xsoup = BeautifulSoup(webpage ,'html5lib').find('body')  
xmainTable = xsoup.find('table', id ="list_view_table")
print(xmainTable)*
```

When I do this I get

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="display" id="list_view_table">
        <thead>
            <tr id="list_view_header">
                <th id="lvh0" width="60">Source</th>
                <th id="lvh1" width="70">Date</th>
                <th id="lvh2" width="200">Summary</th>
                <th id="lvh3" width="100">Disease</th>
                <th id="lvh4" width="100">Location</th>
                <th id="lvh5" width="95">Species</th>
                <th id="lvh6" width="60">Cases</th>
                <th id="lvh7" width="60">Deaths</th>
                <th id="lvh8" width="95">Significance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

as an output. But there's nothing in the tbody

when looking at the html code I can see the 'tr'.
How do I get this access to this info.

Comment: that is a kind of dynamic site, you need to use something like PhantomJS to scrap this site

Comment: Selenium would be another option, if you need full automation. If you don't, and especially if you don't need to do this often, then you could simply run BeautifulSoup against a file saved from your browser.

Comment: So I've saved the website to my directory and run **xsoup = BeautifulSoup(open(baseUrl).read(), "html.parser")** but it cant decode it. Is it even possible using python